# How to symbolically evaluate expression within If[]?

Tags: evaluation, symbolic, conditional

I have a function, say `f`, that needs to take one of two symbolic forms depending on the value of its inputs. This function is part of a very large expression, and I'd like to evaluate the entire superexpression symbolically (in order to write it to a `.m` file for future numeric evaluation).

I find that since my function contains an `If[]` statement, I cannot get it to evaluate the arguments of `If[]` symbolically. As a minimal example, take

```
f[x1] = a;
f[x2] = b;
g[y_] := If[y > 0, f[x1], f[x2]];
```

I find that `g[y]` evaluates to `If[y > 0, f[x1], f[x2]]`, but I would like it to evaluate to `If[y > 0, a, b]`. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) instead, which is designed for functions that take different values depending on some condition (it also plays nicer with a large part of the symbolic functionality of Mathematica).

You can either use [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) to convert the `If`:

```
f[x1] = a;
f[x2] = b;
g[y_] := If[y > 0, f[x1], f[x2]];

PiecewiseExpand@g[y]
(* Piecewise[{{a, y > 0}}, b] *)
```

Or redefine `g` directly:

```
g[y_] := Piecewise[{{f[x1], y > 0}}, f[x2]]

g[y]
(* Piecewise[{{a, y > 0}}, b] *)
```

Comment: Or use an immediate assignment: `g[y_] = Piecewise[{{f[x1], y > 0}}, f[x2]]` to evaluate the subexpressions as desired at definition-time instead of at use-time.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that one solution is to use the `Evaluate[]` function, as in the following:

```
f[x1] = a;
f[x2] = b;
g[y_] := If[y > 0, Evaluate[f[x1]], Evaluate[f[x2]]];
```

This achieves the desired outcome.